# c# Serializing large objects using JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am having a massive issue with JSON serialization.

within my app, I have the following function defined with one of the Web API controllers.

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("all")]
[Route("api/customers/all/")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(Models.Response.ResponseError))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, Type = typeof(Models.Response.ResponseErrorBasic))]
public Models.Response.ResponseApiList<Models.Api.Customer> GetValuesAll(DateTime? since=null)
```

Models.Api.Customer is a complex object referencing a couple of related objects.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set}
    .....
    public List<Invoices> Invoices {get;set;}
    .....
    ..... 
}
```

Models.Response.ResponseApiList holds the returned data

```
public class ResponseApiList<T>
{
    public ResponseMeta meta { get; set; } // ResponseMeta holds datetime and total records
    public List<T> payload { get; set; }   // Holds the Customer object 
    public ResponseApiList()
    {
        payload = new List<T>();
        meta = new ResponseMeta();
    }
```

Finally, the following is in the WebApiConfig

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

The NewtonSoft.JSON library is loaded, but am not sure what to look for to see if it is in use.

Anyway, the issue is of performance. Currently, around 11,000 records are returned from the database to be processed, but the total size of the data (based on what fiddler informs me), is 45Mbs.

When the c# code returns from the function, the total time taken is approx. 4 seconds.

Then, nothing for a very long time. Today I started the process at 11:43 and it did not stop until 15:34. My testing tools are ReadyAPI (SoapUI) and Insomnia.

Ultimately, this is going to be converted into a paged call to reduce the amount of data sent, but what are the limits of sending JSON back from a Web API method?

Before I go down the recode route, does anyone has a way of doing this any other way?

Comment: Any JSON serializer/deserializer uses Reflection internally to convert  JSON to an object or vice-versa. In the case of very large objects, it eventually will take time but how long it depends upon the size. Are you showing all 11,000 records in UI which I believe user can't read them all. Instead it can be fetched on demand using pagination. Let me know what are you trying to achieve with fetching all the records at once. I'm looking for not to change serialization logic and achieve things differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all - Sending such monstrous responses (45Mb) is very weird idea. I can't invent any case when such large data-object is useful.
2. If you have larger collection of items - the best way is paginated output. Limit/offset for example.

> Ultimately, this is going to be converted into a paged call to reduce the amount of data sent, but what are the limits of sending JSON back from a Web API method?

I believe that there are no hard web-API-level restrictions on response size. And especially this issue isn't related to json-serializer. Limits in this extremely-large-response-scenario most likely will appear on webserver configuration level. (Something like max-response size and so on).

But the main conclusion of this situation should be - "If json object is 45Mb large - something goes wrong."

Comment: Thank you all. Firstly this was a dba's idea, a copy of some of the main database is written to an iOS app so that it can run offline. You have confirmed my suspicions. I am going to add a last updated value to the tables so that the query only has to bring back changed records after the last update. This will reduce the data to almost nothing.